# Unexpected encoding error using JSON.parse

Tags: ruby, json, encoding

I've got a rather large JSON file on my Windows machine and it contains stuff like `\xE9`. When I `JSON.parse` it, it works fine.

However, when I push the code to my server running CentOS, I always get this: `"\xE9" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)`

Here is the output of `file` on both machines

Windows:

```
λ file data.json
data.json: UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

CentOS:

```
$ file data.json
data.json: UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Here is the error I get when trying to parse it:

```
$ ruby -rjson -e 'JSON.parse(File.read("data.json"))'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/json/common.rb:155:in `encode': "\xC3" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)
```

What could be causing this problem? I've tried using iconv to change the file into every possible encoding I can, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"\xE9"` is `é` in ISO-8859-1 (and various other ISO-8859-X encodings and Windows-1250 and ...) and is certainly not UTF-8.

You can get [`File.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-read) to fix up the encoding for you by using the [encoding options](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new-label-Options):

```
File.read('data.json',
  :external_encoding => 'iso-8859-1',
  :internal_encoding => 'utf-8'
)
```

That will give you a UTF-8 encoded string that you can hand to `JSON.parse`.

Or you could let `JSON.parse` deal with the encoding by using just `:external_encoding` to make sure the string comes of the disk with the right encoding flag:

```
JSON.parse(
  File.read('data.json',
    :external_encoding => 'iso-8859-1',
  )
)
```

You should have a close look at `data.json` to figure out why **file(1)** thinks it is UTF-8. The file might incorrectly have a BOM when it is not UTF-8 or someone might be mixing UTF-8 and Latin-1 encoded strings in one file.

Comment: The thing is, I own the file in question; Is it possible for me to fiddle with the encodings of the file directly to solve this or do I have to do it from Ruby?  After reading your answer, I tried converting the file to ISO-8859-1 but it still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: The file already is ISO-8859-1. You could read it into Ruby, convert the encoding to UTF-8 (as in the first `File.read` example), and then write it back out. That would leave you with a UTF-8 encoded file.